# 4-Byte CONNACK message is divided into 2 packages to deliver using MQTT library in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm using the Node.js and MQTT library([mqtt-connection](https://github.com/mqttjs/mqtt-connection)) to implement an MQTT server. It works well but recently I encounter an issue that the CONNACK message, which is only 4-byte long, is divided into two TCP packages by server.
[image: 0x20 02 00 00]

I've checked the source code of MQTT.js, but can't figure out where's the problem.
[image]
If this is not fixed, I think massive of throughput may be wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed. 
The reason is that two write statement may have an interval, causing TCP stream sends them into two different TCP packages.